# Passport Authenticate function is not working in node api

Tags: node.js, api, express, jwt

I am creating token using `jwt-simple` node module at the time of login.
below is my code:

```
apiRoutes.put('/login', function(req, res, next){
  User.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function(err, user){
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result){
       if(result){
        var token=jwt.encode(user,config.secret);
        return res.json({token:token});         
      }else{
        return res.json("Incorrect Email and Password")
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Token is creating successfully.
Now I am trying to authenticate the user in `/dashboard` route.

```
apiRoutes.get('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) { 
    var token=getToken(req.headers);
  if(token){
    var decode=jwt.decode(token, config.secret);
    User.findOne({name:decode.name}, function(err, user){
      if(err){res.json(err)}
        if(!user){
          return res.status(403).send({success:false, msg:'Authentication Failed'})
        }else{
          res.json({success:true, msg:'Welcome in the Area' +user.name+'!'})
        }
    })
  }else{
    return res.status(403).send({success:false, msg:'No Token Found'})
  }

  });


getToken = function (headers) {
      if (headers && headers.authorization) {
        var parted = headers.authorization.split(' ');
        if (parted.length === 2) {
          return parted[1];
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
```

Issue is that, when I am hitting this API on `postman` its showing `Unauthorized` and when I remove passport authentication function `passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})` from the route then its printing `success:false, msg:'No Token Found'`.
I don't know how to fix this problem. Please have a look at my code and let me know where is my fault.

Help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is purpose if using passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})? And what it gives in token when you debug or log it.

Comment: `passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})` is using to check token is valid or not. But when I am using it on route then its giving `Unauthorized`.   That means `token` is not valid or what??? I am not getting

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding. You need to define a strategy before using passport.authenticacte() function. Check [this link](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) . And I think you can just use [passport-jwt module](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt) instead of simple-jwt. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am following [this](https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/) tutorial.  and its working fine even he is also using `jwt-simple`.

Comment: So have you created jwt strategy as per the tutorial? Check the "Creating our Strategy and User" section in the tutorial.

Comment: And are you sure you are receiving the token through headers in the getToken function in parted[1] variable?

Comment: May be not. How to check?

Comment: Just print the headers.authorization and let me know what you get

Comment: The value should be in the format "Basic <token>". Is it like that? as the code is splitting it with space.

Comment: `JWTeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ODJjMGQyMmY1ZjUwMDJlMGNjMzQ3MGUiLCJuYW1lIjoic2F1cmFiaCIsImVtYWlsIjoic2F1cmFiaEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiQyYSQxMCQ5bUNseFFhMXQ5TnpxaWpxc3c5UjZPNzdiaWtGVDJBY2JzZE4vUjgybGFmRjMyMy51bjdDUyIsIl9fdiI6MCwic3RhdHVzIjoiWWVzIn0.ZquD0t_UPkTI5ZPOf1QgaLU7HZlfn5gn6hIkzsaQml0` this is format after splitting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129316/discussion-between-sagar-gopale-and-saurabh-sharma).